# Incorrect syntax near 'as' when added calculated column

Tags: sql, syntax, calculated-columns

I need to add a calculated column from 2 other columns in the same table but I have this error "Incorrect syntax near 'as'."

```
alter table [test].[S937] add [new col] as ([col a] * [col b])
```

I have full rights on the database.

When I try to add the column "empty" it works, values are all NULL :

```
alter table [test].[S937] add [new col] varchar(9)
```

The table was created by multiple joins and works absolutely fine.

```
SELECT table1.col1 AS [namecol1], table2[col2] as [namecol2], table3[col3] as [namecol3] into test.S937 FROM table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT...) LEFT JOIN (SELECT...) UNION
```

Comment: why would you like multiply varchars?

Comment: It was just a test, it's actually a FLOAT and works fine with FLOAT too :)

Comment: What issue are you facing? It's generating ERROR? or values are inserting incorrectly?

Comment: ERROR message -> The query couldn't launch because of this Parse error at line: 2, column: 42: Incorrect syntax near 'as'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. [Here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=162b25313599811b0bee89871f918431)

But you can also create the column first, and update it [next](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3d4b016995b7d483706d7430708896c).

Comment: Hi thanks a lot ! I know it should work but it doesnt that's why I needed help.. No idea where the problem comes from but create then update works good :D